# Has live streaming Stack Exchange podcasts been discontinued?

Tags: discussion, podcast

Previously, the Stack Exchange podcasts were live streamed on YouTube or Livestream. However, the last live streamed podcast was from [September 1st](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512/2015/9/1); there have been [two](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/11/podcast-69-its-too-rainy-for-a-parade/) [additional](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/podcast-70-david-was-wrong-and-jason-was-right/) podcasts since then. Has the practice of live streaming the podcasts been discontinued? Or was this a temporary pause in the live streaming process?

Comment: It was never very permanent.. You'll note we haven't even had a podcast since January.